# WPF : Know which Control is clicked on Datagrid

Tags: wpf, button, datagrid, click

I have a DataGrid bounded to OservableCollection populated cols and rows dynamically. The DataGrid's row has couple of buttons. On each button a method is called (have implemented AddHandler while generating columns).

In the handler method, I can get which row was selected. I want to know the button of which column was selected. Based on that only I can take action and open respective windows.

How do I know which button of the row was selected ?

Comment: different handlers? or you can check the sender ( or sender's datacontext)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the column using :

```
int col = myDataGrid.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex;
int row = seivesTorGrid.SelectedIndex;
```

Based on this I am able to code respective actions.